# ComboBox разбивает string на char

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Забиндил к `ComboBox` коллекцию и обратился к свойству `Name` из этой коллекции, но получаю не `Фамилия Имя Отчество`, `char[]`. Как пофиксить?

`OrganizationUser` - сотрудник организации, имеет свойство `Name`, `Id` (оба свойства `string`). Этот класс писал не я, он из API.

Во `ViewModel`:

```
class ViewModel
{
   public List<OrganizationUser> Users { get; set; }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource={Binding Users/Name} />
```

Выглядит вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, что `Name` - это строковое свойство модели, то получится вот так.

```xml
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
```

Comment: Спасибо, проблема решена

Answer (score 1):

В продолжении слов <kbd>aepot</kbd>.
Ты можешь добавить отображаемые параметры, как это сказал aepot. А также можешь сделать параметр значения (не отображаемый).

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" SelectedValuePath="Value"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"></ComboBox>
```

*<kbd>Value</kbd> - придуманный параметр, вместо него ты можешь подставить, допустим, ID человека.*